# Get file from aws s3 and compare

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-s3

```
#!/bin/bash

set +x

env=$1 


if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
   echo "ERROR: 1 arguments needed"
   echo "\$1:  env"
  

   echo "File $1 does not exist"
   exit 1
 fi
}

check_if_file_exists "$path_to_regional_config"
```

i get an answer like that

@ []
build   21-Jan-2024 20:00:40    + {"ApiUrl":"/api/v1"}

Comment: What's the point in running the output of the aws copy command through `echo`, which modifies the output in various ways?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden" typically indicates that the AWS credentials that are being used do not have the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket.
But probably docker works using your local awscli credentials configured.

If your Bamboo server is running on an EC2 instance, you can assign an IAM role to the EC2 instance that has the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket. And other way is configuring the aws credentials in Bamboo and then use them in your build plan.

Comment: can i use something like asw configure sso but without confirmation?

Comment: You can set up an access key with permissions to use 
 the implicated services: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html